# Error when using case with variables

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i am facing a problem when i use a variable with a case in mysql.

The code which i have used is

```
DECLARE vSite VARCHAR(20);
SET vSite = case 
 when id > 0 then 'sdfsdf' 
 else 'asd' end as name 
from customers;
```

When i run this code it throws me error like

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE vSite VARCHAR(20)' at line 1: DECLARE vSite VARCHAR(20)
```

CAN anyone point me where am going wrong..Thanks for your valuable help

Comment: do not spam with tags. Your question got nothing with PHP

Comment: I mean what are you trying to solve,tell me about the problem not about your solution.

Comment: @Mihai can this be done in stored procedures only ??..can i add the  case statement result into a variable without a stored procedure

Comment: Yeah you can only do it with procedures,functions or triggers OR create a column in the table and INSERT into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare variables inside a BEGIN END block.

Here is a simple example of a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure blah(IN customer_id INT,OUT vSite VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN 
SELECT CASE WHEN id > 0 THEN 'blah'
ELSE 'mah' END INTO vSite FROM customers WHERE id=customer_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL blah(3,@somevar);
SELECT @somevar;
```

Comment: could you please post an sql fiddle

Comment: A link to the documentation and a little example would be nice, no?

Comment: @lovemysql First of all what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mihai i just want to use these case statement from a varibale

Comment: @Mihai can this be done in stored procedures only ??..can i add the case statement result into a variable without a stored procedure